# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mode new not null

Tags: plsql

```
declare
    v_empno empdab.eno%type:=&n;
    v_empdab empdab%rowtype;
    begin
    select eno, ename,doj,position,salary,comm,address into v_empdab from empdab where eno=v_empno;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_empdab.eno||v_empdab.ename||v_empdab.doj||v_empdab.position||v_empdab.salary||v_empdab.comm||v_empdab.address);
end ;
```

Comment: i did not found any issues with this part of code, are you sure is this the complete code or part of code in some procedure

Comment: '&' is used with named parameters in SQL*Plus.  However, here you have a PL/SQL block.  I don't believe you can use SQL*Plus named parameters in a PL/SQL block because PL/SQL simply doesn't understand them.  You'll need to do something else - perhaps turn this into a callable procedure?

Answer (score 2):

SQL*Plus named parameters **can** be used in PL/SQL. I think you have not send us the real code.

```
Script start cc.sql
accept n prompt 'Enter value for n :'

set serveroutput on

declare
   v_v test.v%type := &n;
   r_v test%rowtype;

begin
   dbms_output.put_line(v_v);
   select v into v_v from test where rownum = 1;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_v);
   dbms_output.put_line(&n);

end;
/
End Script cc.sql
```

```
SQL> @cc
Enter value for n :'abc'
old   2:    v_v test.v%type := &n;
new   2:    v_v test.v%type := 'abc';
old   9:    dbms_output.put_line(&n);
new   9:    dbms_output.put_line('abc');
abc
a
abc

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```